# How to get data after successful connecting to socket .io?

Tags: swift, sockets, socket.io

I am new to Socket.IO and don't know how to get data once connection is being established with socket.

Socket.IO have following things

1) URL

2) Path

Please have a look on attached image.

I need a very basic example how to connect iOS swift with socket IO and how can i read data from socket.[image]

```
var manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "url")!, config: [.log(true), .compress,.path("path"),.connectParams(["authorization":"token"])])
var socket = manager.defaultSocket
socket.on("connected") {data, ack in
        print("socket connected")
        print(socket.status)
}
```

It prints sockets is connected but don't know how to process further. How to get conversationList? Will be very Thankful for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the tables is a list of events you have to listen to. `conversationsList` and `messagesList` are a special case because they're bi-directional (meaning you have to emit them as well as receive them. I understand them as a chain. You will only emit conversationsList when you're connected. So the possible solution would be:

```
var manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "url")!, config: [.log(true), .compress,.path("path"),.connectParams(["authorization":"token"])])
var socket = manager.defaultSocket
socket.on("connected") {data, ack in
    print("socket connected")
    print(socket.status)
    socket.emit("conversationsList", ["page": 1])
}

socket.on("conversationsList") {data, ack in
    print("Conversations List received")
    socket.emit("messagesList", ["conversation": "conversation_id", "page": 1])
    print(data)
}
```

You might have to tweak a bit the way data is passed. But the structure should be like this.